# Unable to access get values of other rows other than the first row

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug, mean-stack

I have a json of people objects. I have successfully been able to place these objects in a table. My objective is to place buttons on each row and access the person at each row. Creating a button on each row is the easy part, but making the button correspond to what is on that row is difficult. Any advice? I am new to web development

I have already tried placing a button on each row, hoping that the code would some how know what was on it's row. Also, the strange thing is, when I click the first button in my table it returns me the appropriate name, but when I click the second button in my table it doesn't console.log anything..

```
    div(style = "text-align: center;")
                table.table.table-striped.table-dark
                    thead
                        tr
                            th(scope='col')
                            th(scope='col') Friend
                            th(scope='col') Email
                    tbody
                        each item in json
                            tr
                                td
                                    button(id = 'sendRequest', type = 'submit', value = '#{item.name}', name = 'name')
                                td #{item.name}
                                td #{item.email}
```

I expect to get the name of the specific person on that row when i click the button that is on that row

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be unique within the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id`'s are ment to be **unique**. You could try giving each button a unique generated `id` or `data-` attribute like `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, which can be used to determine what row in the JSON database it wants to access.

As you generate the elements, set the id to something like `= "El" + index`. You can then access it using `... document.getElementById("El" + index)`.